# Consumer.accept() not called for Subject in doOnNext()

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have two `Subject`s, one subscribes to the other for updates.

```
Subject<Integer> subject = new Subject<>() {
    @Override
    public boolean hasObservers() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasThrowable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasComplete() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable getThrowable() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super InitialAPIResponse> observer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onNext: " + apiResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

    }
};

subject.doOnNext(result -> Log.d("Subject", "accept: " + result));

observableSubject
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(subject);

observableSubject.onNext(1);
observableSubject.onComplete();
```

When the `onNext()` is called, the `Consumer`'s `accept()` provided in `doOnNext()` is not. Even though according to the documentation

> **Observable.doOnNext()**
>
> Modifies the source `ObservableSource` so that it invokes an action when it calls `onNext`.
>
> **Scheduler:**
> `doOnNext` does not operate by default on a particular `Scheduler`
>
> `onNext`
> the action to invoke when the source ObservableSource calls `onNext`
>
> **return** the source ObservableSource with the side-effecting behavior applied

From what I understand from the documentation the observable should call the `Consumer` in `doOnNext()`.

I'm learning **`RxJava`** so maybe I'm doing something wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1.

```
subject.doOnNext(result -> Log.d("Subject", "accept: " + result));
```

In above code, the result of `doOnNext` is not subscribed. `doOnNext` does not subscribe to upstream on its own, just as many other operators. Change to this, for example:

```
subject.doOnNext(result -> Log.d("Subject", "accept: " + result)).subscribe();
```

2.

```
observableSubject
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(subject);

observableSubject.onNext(1);
observableSubject.onComplete();
```

In above code, `onComplete` is called immediately after `.onNext`. This can cause timing issues when emitting the values.

Change above code to either

```
observableSubject
            .subscribe(subject); // subscribe on the same thread so that everything happens sequentially. 

observableSubject.onNext(1);
observableSubject.onComplete();
```

or

```
Subject<Integer> observableSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
observableSubject
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(subject);

observableSubject.onNext(1);
// observableSubject.onComplete(); // don't call onComplete/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response a couple of questions: 1. Who would subscribe to `doOnNext`? And Why? 2. Even if the subscription is delayed and subject is complete, being a behavior subject doesn't that mean `Observer` still gets the last passed value? I only added onComplete like this for the example here to show my problem, onNext is called in response to a network call, by which time the `Observer` will have subscribed.

Comment: To be precise I'm having trouble with using RxJava as a replacement for interface Callbacks. I have a repository which exposes a `Subject` to the `UseCase`, the UseCase however has multiple repositories and one repository may or may not depend on the other to complete. This is causing me to write a lot of unnecessary code in order to communicate between the responses from these repositories. I could wrap Observer in an abstract class but I'm not sure if that is the best thing to do.

Comment: The first question is already answered. You need `.subscribe` to trigger the flow. Your question might be more like "Why need to have both `.doOnNext` and `.subscribe` when they both do almost the same thing?". `do...` operators produces side effects and you must not have any logic inside that can affect the stream in any possible way. Some valid use cases are logging and testing. Invalid use cases include updating UI, calling some other functions, interacting with other observables, updating member variables, etc.

Comment: Answer for the second question is that the observer won't get any additional value from any completed stream regardless whether it is a `BehaviorSubject` or not. I recommend not to use `.onComplete()` on the subject in your case. If you need the stream to complete, then use operators like `.take` or `.first`.